# Julia: remove a package and all its dependencies?

Tags: julia, package

After adding a package, e.g. MarketData, with:

```
Pkg.add("MarketData")
```

which also installs dependencies:

```
INFO: Installing BufferedStreams v0.4.0
INFO: Installing Codecs v0.4.0
...
```

how can I remove or uninstall the package and all its dependencies?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/pkg/#Base.Pkg.rm):

```
Pkg.rm("MarketData")
```

> `rm(pkg)`
>
> Remove all requirement entries for `pkg` from `Pkg.dir("REQUIRE")` and call `Pkg.resolve()`.

This also removes dependencies:

```
INFO: Removing BufferedStreams v0.4.0
INFO: Removing Codecs v0.4.0
...
```

Comment: Users may also want to run `pkg> gc` to clean up removed packages from the `packages` directory. Also note, this step does not remove content from the `dev` or `compiled` folder. They must be deleted manually (after `free` has been run).

Comment: Hi, unfortunately trying rm is giving me an error
`The following package names could not be resolved:
* MyPackage (not found in project or Manifest)`
Even `free` doesn't work. gives me same error

Comment: @KugelBlitz Sorry, I stopped using Julia a few years ago. You may have better luck asking a new question.

Comment: That's fine, I just deleted the whole folder and ran it again which resolved my issue, turned out it was no big deal!

Comment: Perhaps first, we need to know how to list installed packages

Answer (score 6):

Step 1: Press ] to go to package manager .
Step 2: Type `rm MarketData`

Tested on v1.6